# Browserify to minify and concat files

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a purely web-based app (ie no Node server) and I want to be able to bundle all my JS files and CSS files for each page of the web app.

I was using Gulp to simply minify and concat my JS and CSS files into one bundle, but found that the order in which I supplied the files was then spewed out randomly (unacceptable if you ask me...). I tried `gulp-order` and other stream ordering modules with more random results.

I want to try `browserify` but I am stuck on two things

1. Do I need to do `module.exports` when using browserify? Think of my web app as extremely basic.. It requires jQuery, bootstrap, and my own libraries. There is nothing past the complexity of having to include the files in the right order
2. Why when I try to use `browserify` with a build file, as opposed to the command line, does it seem to try and bundle every single thing it requires? I only want to bundle the things that my `app.js` has a `require()` to

Eg.

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var fs = require('fs');
var b = browserify();
b.add('./app.js');
b.transform({
    global: true
}, 'uglifyify');

b.bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./bundle.js'));
```

When I run `browserify build.js` it spews out maybe 100 files into stdout. I am trying to replicate what happens when I run `browserify -g uglifyify app.js > bundle.js` -> this takes all requires() from app.js and bundles it into a new file.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to be able to `require` your modules / code in other parts of your application, you'll be required to use `module.exports`. Otherwise you don't need to export anything.
2. Browserify only bundles the dependencies that are required, but it also does this recursively, meaning if your application requires library a and library a requires library b, then browserify will bundle your code, library a and library b.

Comment: I can run this cmd `browserify -g uglifyify app.js > bundle.js` and I get what I want: app.js and everything that it `require()`s and nothing more. I was hoping to do that in a file instead. Also I am not using gulp anymore.

Comment: yeah, now the problem is - simply said - that the `browserify` command simply returns a string. In your command (`browserify -g uglifyify app.js > bundle.js`) you pipe the output of the `browserify` command to the file `bundle.js`. The example I put in my answer using gulp does exactly the same. In my example, `b.bundle()` only returns a string and in order for gulp to be able to store that to a file (`bundle.js`), you need to use (`source('bundle.js')`) which redirects the output of `b.bundle()` into a file called `bundle.js`. Or maybe I am misinterpreting your question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doing that (bundling?) in a file instead"?

Comment: When I was using gulp, I could write a gulpfile.js that took care of many gulp `tasks`. I was assuming, possibly incorrectly, that I could do the same with `browerify`. IE for all of my web pages, instead of running `browserify -g uglifyify webpage1.js > webpage1.min.js` I could put all these commands in a single file and only build once.

Comment: I think I will give up and go back to gulp, and then manually sort out its senseless concat order.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Well, you could obviously write some bash scripts that take care of this, but browserify itself is probably not the right tool for the task. You might wanna take a look at webpack (https://github.com/webpack/webpack) - since it is designed to take care of all common build tasks and still focused around providing a simple bundle in the end. However, if your tasks are more complex then simple postprocessing that is supported by plugins out of the box, gulp is probably the way to go